Call viewmodel function only one time when composable opened - Compose Android
When the compose screen is opened for the first time, I want to call function like list api or detail api.
I am currently using LaunchEffect(true) to call such function but the issue is that it is called again when configuration change is made like device is rotated, font changed, light/dark mode etc.
As the data is not updated and only design should change in the situation.
What is the most efficient way to do this?

This question is similar to: Android Jetpack Compose call view-model function only once. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In order to avoid the LaunchedEffect(true) from being triggered again on configuration changes, you can use rememberSaveable or remember to store a flag indicating that the function has been already called.
var apiCalled by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

if (!apiCalled) {
    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        // Call your API here
        apiCalled = true
    }
}

Note:

remember: To store a flag that persists across recompositions but not across process death or state destruction.
rememberSaveable: If you want to preserve the flag across process death or configuration changes like rotation, dark mode, etc.


A good solution, but there is a better way to do it

What happens when api is called once and savable variable is true and user closes the app completely and then opens again will the api call be done again? Or will the screen become stagnant. I think it will remain stagnant and wont disturb the app flow

If you use rememberSaveable, the state will persist across configuration changes but not when the app is completely closed (killed) and reopened. When the user reopens the app after closing it, the app will restart from a fresh state, and the API call will be triggered again since the rememberSaveable variable will revert to its default value (e.g., false).

okay, thanks for the details

rememberSaveable does not "preserve the flag across process death". It only survives the recreation of the activity (onDestroy and onCreate). If you want to keep data that survives process death you need to store it on disk (using SavedStateHandle, a DataStore or a database like Room).

This works but consider that using the "view" to signal required internal behaviour of a view model is a code smell - this produces a tight and brittle coupling.

There are 3 major ways to achieve this logic

Most basic is LaunchEffect(true)

class AbcViewModel : ViewModel() {
    
    fun test() { }

}

@Composable
fun TestComposable() {
    val viewModel : AbcViewModel = viewModel()

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        viewModel.test()
    }
}


Use init block of viewModel (Most viable)

class AbcViewModel : ViewModel() {

    fun test() { }

    init {
        test()
    }

}

@Composable
fun TestComposable() {
    val viewModel : AbcViewModel = viewModel()
}

This logic helps solve all the drawbacks from the first solution.
But this means that every time we initialize the view model the function will be called without any conditioning and cant do anything about it.

Use flow collection (Advance)

class AbcViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _isLoading = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isLoading = _isLoading
        .onStart {
            test()
        }
        .stateIn(
            viewModelScope,
            SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5.seconds),
            false
        )

    fun test() { }

}

@Composable
fun TestComposable() {
    val viewModel: AbcViewModel = viewModel()
    val loadingState by viewModel.isLoading.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
}

Using this method we can do conditioning too which we cant do in the previous solution.
Here 5 seconds are for the wait which viewmodel will do before making the flow reset. So if the composable will collect the flow in that 5 seconds it will not be reset and data will be restored directly.
As this is a bit advance, if you dont understand it fully 2nd solution will be alright to use too.

This is what view model's are for.
The view model survives the lifetime of a composable so you won't have any issues with recomposition, configuration changes (why LaunchedEffect won't work) or even the composable leaving and reentering the composition (why rememberSaveable won't work).
Furthermore, your composables should only concern themselves with displaying the UI. Calling an API, waiting for a response, transforming data and so on should all be done in the lower layers of your app. The general idea is that your view model hides all of that from your composables. It stores all the data needed and exposes it as StateFlows so your composable can easily react to data changes.
Any api calls or initialization must therefore be done in the view model. There are basically two approaches:

Make the API call in the view model's init block. It is only executed once when the view model is created (which is only done once per Activity, so you are unaffected by configuration changes).
Assuming api.call() is a suspending function returning a String:
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)
    val state = _state.asStateFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _state.value = api.call()
        }
    }
}


Better yet, if your API already returns a Flow, you can directly transform it into a StateFlow in the property declaration.
Assuming api.call() returns a Flow<String>:
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val state = api.call()
        .stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
            initialValue = null,
        )
}



Whatever you choose, your composables can now simply collect the StateFlow and work with its value:
val state: String? by viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

At first state will be null, but as soon as the API call in the view model finishes the composable will recompose and state will contain the String that was returned from the API.
This is the solution to your problem: Your composables do not even know anything about the API and therefore do not need to concern themselves how they can mange to only call it once.
